# Compare queries on PostgreSQL and MySQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Have a nice day!

On Windows Azure On Small VM with Debian 7.1 I installed MySQL 5.5.31 and PostgreSQL 9.2.4.
Insert and Select queries will make from php via pdo.

Creating table:

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ftext` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ix_date` (`fdate`),
  KEY `ix_text` (`ftext`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

PgSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  fdate timestamp without time zone,
  ftext character varying(1000),
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE test
  OWNER TO postgres;

CREATE INDEX ix_date
  ON test
  USING btree
  (fdate);

CREATE INDEX ix_text
  ON test
  USING btree
  (ftext COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Make Inserts into tables.

Data is like this:

```
152 2013-07-25 00:01:47 51e811712cfd6
100151  2013-07-25 00:28:25 51e825bfea275
101151  2013-07-25 00:29:26 51e825fcc5d94
153 2013-07-25 01:01:47 51e8117134c14
100152  2013-07-25 01:28:25 51e825bff1eb7
101152  2013-07-25 01:29:26 51e825fccd9e7
154 2013-07-25 02:01:47 51e811713d80d
100153  2013-07-25 02:28:25 51e825c0077c7
101153  2013-07-25 02:29:26 51e825fcd561a
155 2013-07-25 03:01:47 51e811716ffb2
100154  2013-07-25 03:28:25 51e825c013225
101154  2013-07-25 03:29:26 51e825fcdd243
156 2013-07-25 04:01:47 51e8117179af0
100155  2013-07-25 04:28:25 51e825c01cd74
101155  2013-07-25 04:29:26 51e825fce3f1c
```

In each table inserted 102 000 rows.

Average time of insert:

```
MySQL: 0.0328167504 сек.
PgSQL: 0.0183281872 сек.
- PgSQL is ~twice faster.
```

Then I make select:

```
select * from test 
where `fdate` > "2013-07-25" and `fdate` < "2013-08-21" 
order by `fdate`
```

(SELECTs made in FOR loop (1000), and then calculate average time.)

```
MySQL: 0.0004650463 сек., 1944 rows
PgSQL: 0.0139540959 сек., 1944 rows
- PgSQL by 30! times more slowly.
```

Why?

PgSQL EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS):

```
"Index Scan using ix_date on test  (cost=0.00..36.86 rows=780 width=30) (actual time=0.018..4.672 rows=1944 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: ((fdate > '2013-07-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (fdate < '2013-08-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"  Buffers: shared hit=1954"
"Total runtime: 7.594 ms"
```

MySQL EXPLAIN:

```
1   SIMPLE  test    range   ix_date ix_date 8       1942    Using where
```

analyze VERBOSE test (PgSQL):

```
INFO:  analyzing "public.test"
INFO:  "test": scanned 750 of 750 pages, containing 102000 live rows and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 102000 estimated total rows
```

Comment: Show the execution plans for both DBMS. Did you analyze the Postgres tables? Btw: the select as shown will not run on Postgres. Also: did you tune the Postgres server in any way? The default settings are pretty conservative. More details on how to ask performance related questions are here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: Also, the two databases are reporting different numbers of rows which makes the test a bit iffy. And make sure you are measuring time to return all the rows on both, not time to return the first row with MySQL. Oh, and please don't call columns things like "date" or "int" or "select" - even when it doesn't confuse the RDBMS it confuses poor human readers.

Comment: Did not tune.
PgSQL explain:
"Sort  (cost=1241.28..1249.31 rows=3210 width=26)"
"  Sort Key: date"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test  (cost=101.18..1054.33 rows=3210 width=26)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((date > '2013-07-25'::date) AND (date < '2013-08-21'::date))"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_date  (cost=0.00..100.38 rows=3210 width=0)"
"              Index Cond: ((date > '2013-07-25'::date) AND (date < '2013-08-21'::date))"

Comment: MySQl explain:
1 SIMPLE test ALL ix_date  123193 Using where; Using filesort

Comment: analyze VERBOSE test (pgsql):
INFO:  analyzing "public.test"
INFO:  "test": scanned 905 of 905 pages, containing 123000 live rows and 0 dead rows; 30000 rows in sample, 123000 estimated total rows

Comment: SELECTs made in FOR loop (1000), and then calculate average time.

Comment: when you do benchmarks, you should disable all query caches!

Comment: Please don't post code or execution plans as comments. Edit your question and format them properly.

Comment: Why? I need a real environment.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I copied theirs to question.

Comment: If you inserted 123000 rows in each database, how come the Postgres query returns a completely different amount of rows than MySQL?

Comment: Quick tip for working with MySQL and another DB together: Consider running MySQL in `ANSI` mode with the `STRICT` options set. It'll let you use ANSI standard quoting, eg `"identifier"` and `'literal`', instead of MySQL's funky quoting.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, inserts made different packs (for example, 1000, then 8000, then 2000 and etc.) for test inserts.

Comment: I remade my test with "human readers" columns and equivalent count of rows by select queries. Result became even worse.

Comment: It is completely pointless to test performance with an RDBMS that you did not tune to your hardware settings (and properly so). Comparing numbers like you do without specifying a lot more circumstances, is also pointless.

Comment: @programmister Regarding needing a "real" environment, this is clearly not a "real" scenario - it is very unlikely that your actual application would perform a sequence of operations in this way. Turning off specific features that give one DBMS an advantage in the artificial scenario gives you better (or at least different) information about behaviour in other scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

The repeated query hit the MySQL [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache.html), a feature which, I believe, does not exist in PostgreSQL.

Repeat the test after [disabling the query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_type), or add the [`SQL_NO_CACHE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-in-select.html) directive to your query to MySQL (`SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM test...`).

Comment: Another way to rule out any caching of this kind if you don't know the details of the system you are benchmarking is to deliberately vary your queries/operations in an unpredictable pattern rather than repeating identical operations.